# Is daemon thread lighter than normal thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm new in Java world so at the moment I'm learning about Threads.
I've read that daemon thread is described as background task, so I thought that it means it's lighter than the normal thread.

I also read next about daemons on Wikipedia:
"A daemon is a type of background process designed to run continually in the background, waiting for event(s) to occur or condition(s) to be met.These processes typically use minimal system resources and perform tasks which require little to no input from the user."

Comment: The _daemon processes_ that you read about are from a time long ago when computer networking and inter-process communication were in their infancy.  A typical example would be a _printer daemon_ running on a time-shared mainframe system.  The daemon would wake up every minute or so and examine its _spool directory_.  If any files were there, it would send them to the printer, delete them, and then go back to sleep.  Users or user programs then could print simply by dropping a file in the spool directory.  "Daemon" doesn't mean that anymore.  Now it mostly is just another way to say "service".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, the *only* difference between daemon threads and non-daemon threads in Java is that a non-daemon thread prevents the JVM from terminating, whereas a daemon one doesn't: once all non-daemon threads have completed, the JVM will exit.